# Destroying a process if it takes too much time

Tags: java, multithreading

I am executing a shell script from my Java program using `Process` and I want to kill/destroy that process if my script takes long time.

I came up with this code and wanted to see if there is any better way or anything I can improve on.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Your script
        String script = getScriptTextFromSomewhere();

        // create a temp file and write your script to it
        File tempScript = File.createTempFile("temp_scripts_", "");
        tempScript.setExecutable(true);
        try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempScript)) {
            output.write(script.getBytes());
        }

        // build the process object and start it
        List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
        commandList.add(tempScript.getAbsolutePath());
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.environment().put("param1", "abc");
        builder.environment().put("param2", "xyz");
        Process shell = builder.start();

        // read the output and show it
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shell.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

        // wait for the process to finish
        WaitingThread thread = new WaitingThread(shell);
        thread.start();
        long timeoutMillis = 20000;
        thread.join(timeoutMillis);
        if(thread.isAlive()) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }

        if(!thread.isFinished()) {
            shell.destroy();
            shell.waitFor();
            System.out.println("PROCESS WAS INTERRUPTED");
        } else {
            // check the exit code (exit code = 0 usually means "executed ok")
            System.out.println("PROCESS FINISHED, EXIT CODE: " + thread.getExitValue());
        }

        // delete temp file
        tempScript.delete();
    }
}

class WaitingThread extends Thread {

    private int exitValue;
    private Process shell;
    private boolean finished = false;

    public WaitingThread(Process shell) {
        this.shell = shell;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            exitValue = shell.waitFor();
            finished = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            finished = false;
        }
    }

    public int getExitValue() {
        return exitValue;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finished;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, I'm not *too sure* how your code works... your timeout starts ***after*** you begin to read the `stdout` of the spun `Process` object for non-`null` lines, but if you read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) of `BufferedReader.readLine()` again:

> **Returns:**
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

If my understanding of how the `stdout` pipelining done by the `Process` object is correct (wells, this being *OS-dependent* and what-not), I think the end of `Process.getInputStream()` is reached when the *native process* is disconnected. In most scenarios, said process would have completed too, unless we are talking about starting daemon processes.

In other words, the timeout check becomes a dummy step when it is reached, and `thread.isFinished()` will most likely return `true`, always.

**Second**, since you are already on Java 7 at least, you should be relying on a combination of [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) implementations to achieve your goal as they arguably have better semantics for performing timeout checks.

For example, since all you need is to run one background thread, you can use [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--):

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Then, since you do not require a return value, you can [`submit()` a `Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-), and call the resulting `Future`'s [`get(long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method:

```
Runnable runnable = createRunnableForProcessHandling(shell);
Future<?> future = service.submit(runnable);
try {
    future.get(timeout, timeoutUnit);
    // completed within timeout
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // do something about the timeout
} finally {
    service.shutdown();
}
```

The alternative is to [`submit()` a `Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) to get perhaps the output of the native process as a `List`, for further processing:

```
Callable<List<String>> callable = getOutputLinesFrom(shell);
Future<List<String>> future = service.submit(callable);
try {
    List<String> outputLines = future.get(timeout, timeoutUnit);
    // do something with outputLines
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // do something about the timeout
} finally {
    service.shutdown();
}
```